# How to print total table row in SAPUI5 table

Tags: sapui5

I am trying this example in this I have to add total product count number i.e. total table rows display on screen.

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Table/preview

When I try to Access length of JSON object i.e.:

```xml
<headerToolbar>
    <Toolbar>
        <Label text="Products"></Label>
        <Label text=""{ path: '/ProductCollection', formatter: 'sap.m.sample.Table.Formatter.totalFormatter' }""> </Label>
    </Toolbar>
</headerToolbar>
totalFormatter:function(results) { return results.length; }
```

I get SAPUI5 is not render error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you´d show some of your code. If you´re using databinding with your table you can simply print the size of the aggregation bound to the table but let´s see some code first to be more specific to your use case.

Comment: I am trying this example in this I have to add total product count number i.e. total table rows display on screen https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Table/preview

Comment: What Tim meant is, what have you tried yourself to get the total number of rows displayed? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I answer your question by modifying the code of your example.

1. Edit the Table.view.xml, add one label in the Toolbar.

```xml
<headerToolbar>
    <Toolbar>
        <Label text="Products"></Label>
        <Label text=""
            {
                path: '/ProductCollection',
                formatter: 'sap.m.sample.Table.Formatter.totalFormatter'
            }"">
        </Label>
    </Toolbar>
</headerToolbar>
```

2. Edit the formatter.js, add one method totalFormatter.

```js
totalFormatter:function(results) {
    return results.length;
}
```

Then you will get the total table row.

The basic idea is to utilize the Calculated Fields of Data binding to get the result length. The documentation can be found [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/0c803921b1bf4b3a97a038fbd51ef542.html).

Comment: When I try to Access length of JSON Object i.e 


<headerToolbar>
  <Toolbar>
    <Label text="Products"></Label>
    <Label text=""{
          path: '/ProductCollection',
          formatter: 'sap.m.sample.Table.Formatter.totalFormatter'
        }"">
    </Label>
  </Toolbar>
</headerToolbar>



totalFormatter:function(results) {
        return results.length;
 }


I get SAP UI is not render 

error >> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined